# Searching table by id and other fields in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to do a search on the following fields in my rails model: id, description, notes, and customer_name.

In my model `TechServiceSpecial`:

```
def self.search(params)
  q = "%#{params[:search].try(:strip).tr('%', '')}%"

  #build up general search
  general_search_fields.reduce(nil) do |running_query, field|
    if field =~ /id/
      main_check = arel_table[field].eq(q.to_i)
    else
      main_check = arel_table[field].matches(q)
    end

    if running_query.nil?
      main_check
    else
      running_query.or(main_check)
    end
  end
end

private

def self.general_search_fields
  %i(id description notes customer_name)
end
```

In my controller (I'm using Kaminari for pagination):

```
def search
  specials = TechServiceSpecial.where(TechServiceSpecial.search(params))
  @tech_service_specials = specials.page(params[:page]).per(200)
  render 'index'
end
```

This will not find a record if I search using an id. So, if I have a record with id of 1005, that record will not be returned in the search results for '1005', unless the description, notes or customer_name also happen to have 1005 in them. Any record that happens to have 1005 in the description, notes, or customer_name will be returned.

So, I tweaked the controller to look like this:

```
def search
  specials = TechServiceSpecial.where(TechServiceSpecial.search(params))
  specials.merge(TechServiceSpecial.where(id: params[:search].to_i))
  @tech_service_specials = specials.page(params[:page]).per(200)
  render 'index'
end
```

But I get the same results. Will not return the record with an id of 1005.

How can I make this return a record that has the id that equals the string I'm searching with?

Answer (score 0):

In your `TechServiceSpecial.search` method:

```
q = "%#{params[:search].try(:strip).tr('%', '')}%"
...
if field =~ /id/
  main_check = arel_table[field].eq(q.to_i)
...
```

the value for the id will always be 0, since `q` starts with a "%".

You should set `q` to `params[:search].to_i` if the field is `id`.